# Autocomplete de pesquisa com PHP e Jquery com Banco de Dados

Tags: php, jquery

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando fazer um autocomplete, segui alguns tutoriais na internet e aqui, mas acho que estou pecando em algum detalhe.
Meu input no index.php

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center" >

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite aqui o seu problema com palavras chaves" name="titulo" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" required="" id="auto">
                <span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-left: 10px">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
                </span>


            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


</div>
```

o Javascript no index.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: "procura.php",
        minLength: 1
    });             
});
</script>
```

**procura.php**

```
    <?php
include 'conexao.php';
$titulo = $_GET['titulo'];


    $return_arr = array();

     echo   $sql = "SELECT * FROM artigos where titulo = '%". $titulo  ."%'";
        $busca = oci_parse($conexao, $sql);
        oci_execute($busca);

        while($dados = oci_fetch_array($busca)) {
            $return_arr[] =  $dados['TITULO'];
        }

    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Alguma coisa não está batendo, obrigado!

Comment: Nossa, mas tomei -1 pq?

Comment: provavelmente o erro é o "echo   $sql = ..." que está retornando a sua sql antes do codigo json com os resultados

Comment: você também pode acessar o procura.php?titulo=algumacoisa diretamente no navegador para testar se o retorno está vindo como esperado.